# Using Variables in Zepto Animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax, zepto

I want to use the variable "drawerHeight" in my translateY to specify how much I want the translation to be. I need to get the current height of the div because I plan for the drawer's content to be responsive.

This is one of those situations where I know what I want to do, but can't figure out the syntax to do it.

The code works currently if you replace "drawerHeight" with any fixed em/px amount, but that isn't what I want to do.

```
  var drawerHeight = $(".drawer").css('height');
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
  drawerHeight 
  if (opened == false) {
    $(".drawer").animate({
      translateY: '0',

    }, 600, 'ease-in')  
  }
  if (opened == true) {
    $(".drawer").animate({
      translateY: '-drawerHeight',

    }, 600, 'ease-out')     
   }
    opened = !opened;
   })
```

http://codepen.io/LivMac/pen/WwLEKe

Comment: As a note: in order to be fully responsive I needed to also reduce/increase the opacity so that when you resize the window the contents don't become visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
  translateY: '-drawerHeight',
```

to

```
  translateY: '-' + drawerHeight,
```

---

Also, I'd recommend you to use the `.height()` function available with zepto. That way, your element padding is also taken into consideration.

```
var drawerHeight = $(".drawer").height();
translateY: '-' + drawerHeight + 'px',
```

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/thewisenerd/pen/zqeRQa

Comment: The code pen linked doesn't address the problem fully because as the window is resized it doesn't completely hide the drawer. My current solution at that link does accommodate the resized windows. However, I cannot hide the element properly so that it is not visible after it has been translated up and the window is resized.

Aka I need to some how set opacity to zero for the element or change its visibility AFTER and only after the animation is finished. Not sure how to do that part correctly right now.

Comment: @Liv, that's because you are statically assigning the value of ```drawerHeight```. Move ```var drawerHeight = $(".drawer").css('height');``` into the on click function so that it is calculated dynamically everytime.

also, if you plan on resizing the window often (in between toggles), you should have a on resize function that _corrects_ the translateY since element height might have changed.

Comment: This suggestion helped and I also had to add a conditional to check if the drawer was already set to closed. Otherwise the drawer would close itself on any window resize.